# Test empty Column Datatframe in python spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two different Dataframe:

```
Structure DF1:  A|B|C||E
Structure DF2: A|B||D|E
```

I want to make third Dataframe as the result of the union of these two Dataframes, but first of all, I should do a test between the columns 3 and 4:

```
If column 3 is empty: (Like is my exemple)
    result=column 4

else:
    result=column 3
```

I did a small udf:

```
    def calculcolumn(col3, col4):
        if (col3 is None ):
            return col4
        else:
            return col3

My_udf=calculcolumn(col3,col4)
```

In my example it do not accept an empty column, for example:

```
calculcolumn(,12)
```

I got:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I do an udf to test if a column is empty like in the structure of my dataframe `||` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question or expected result.

spark has the coalesce() function to get the first non-null value.  Will that work?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

lettersSchema = StructType([
  StructField("a", StringType()),
  StructField("b", StringType()),
  StructField("c", StringType()),
  StructField("d", StringType()),
  StructField("e", StringType())
])

# create one row with "c" column null
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("A", "B", None, "D","E")
  ],
  schema=lettersSchema
)

df2.select("a", "b", coalesce("c", "d").alias("c_or_d"), "e").show()
```